# Magento .csv translation and inline translation not working

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.7.

I am trying to change My Account to Your Account as per a video I am watching, yet when I add the following to app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/locale/en_US/translate.csv

```
My Account, Your Account
```

(that is what the guy did in the video, though I am assuming he is using an earlier version) or

```
"My Account", "Your Account"
```

nothing happens.

Also tried editing it with inline translations, I get the little book icon, open it, edit the text, refresh but nothing happens (it is NOT a caching problem).

Any ideas? Maybe some other CSV file is overwriting the one in my custom theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a bit of a caching problem. I basically **disabled ALL caching** and chose **"Default Config"** in system/configuration and now inline translating seems to be working.

So if you are having problems with this just go to cache management and **disable everything**.

Comment: So I go back and try to change "My Wishlist" to "Your Wishlist" and it didn't work (haha), so I refreshed all caching and it worked then. So after you disable all caching, if it doesn't work for something refresh caching but leave it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have use a scope for your translation:

```
"Mage_Customer::My Account", "Your Account"
```